# ComboBox object not accessible by me

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is probably easy to solve, but the following cannot be done:

```
protected void gSelectApplied(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox box = (ComboBox)sender; 
}
```

Because the ComboBox object is not present in the imported libraries. I went ahead an looked at the Microsoft documentation and I do not have access to the System.Windows.* libraries.

Comment: ComboBox doesn't exist in ASP.NET, only in WinForms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the [ASP.NET DropDownList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx).